# php referencing undefined class properties doesn't throw errors

Tags: php

```
<?php

    class test{
        private $s;

        function test(){
        $this->d="test";
        }
    }

    $c=new test();

?>
```

my settings are `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

and php still doesn't notice this issue! What can I do to make php throws exceptions for these types of mistakes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why no PHP error on call to undefined function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897339/why-no-php-error-on-call-to-undefined-function)

Comment: to display the errors, display_errors should be on (display_errors = On)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a property that does not exist is considered bad (E_NOTICE), while setting one simply creates a public property by that name.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class foo
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    var_dump($this->a);
    $this->b = true;
  }
}

new foo;
```

Will give you:

```
Notice: Undefined property: foo::$a on line 7
NULL
```

If you really want to prevent that behavior you can hook into the magic `__get` and `__set` methods that are called when an unknown property is accessed:

```
<?php
class foo
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->doesNotExist = true;
  }

  public function __set($name, $val)
  {
    throw new Exception("Unknown property $name");
  }
}
```

If you want to do this over and over again:

```
<?php
trait DisableAutoProps
{
  public function __get($name)
  {
    throw new Exception("Unknown property $name");
  }
  public function __set($name, $val)
  {
    throw new Exception("Unknown property $name");
  }
}

class foo
{
  use DisableAutoProps;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->doesNotExist = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its not an error. php would get mad if you tried to call an undefined method, but in this case, php is happy to take that statement as a declaration.

```
<?php

    class test{
        private $s;

        function test(){
        $this->d="test";
        }
    }

    $c=new test();
echo $c->d; //"test"

?>
```